# Ruby on Rails: loading html fragment through jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have some difficulties loading my html file as a fragment into a div using the jQuery .load. After a lot of testing my conclusions are that it can't find the c.html file, but I still can't get my head around it after I've been testing almost every possible version of loading to c.html.

index.html.erb and c.html.erb is both located in the same folder, welcome.

Appreciate all help I can get, been going at it for a couple of days now...

Part from the html-file (index.html.erb) where I want to load the fragment:

```
<div id="menuwrapper">
   <div class="tabArea">
      <%= link_to 'Lorem', {:action => 'update', :controller => 'welcome'},
      {:class=>"tab",:remote=>true} %>
   </div>
</div>
<div id="wrapper2">
   <!--Where i want to load-->
</div>
```

welcome_controller:

```
def update
  render :js => "$('#wrapper2').load('c.html.erb', function() {alert('Load was
  performed.');});"
end
```

The html fragment i want to load (as basic as it can get):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head><title>Title</title></head>
  <body>
    <div>Content</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Routes:

```
get "welcome/update"
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Big picture... the javascript you are returning in your `update` method is just that... javascript.  It's executed on the client (browser) side and the browser has no idea what `c.html.erb` is as it's a server side file.

Ways to fix this:

Option 1:  Change `load('c.html.erb'...` to `load('/path/to/c.html.erb' ...`

This method would a little odd, as you would be returning a JS response that does nothing but tell the client to go ping the server again.  Extra round trip for no good reason.

Option 2:

Better option, given your overall approach.

```
# welcome_controller.rb
def update
end

# update.js.erb
$('#wrapper2').html("<%= escape_javascript render(:file => 'c.html.erb') %>");
```